# Reading barcode from large image

Tags: java, image-processing, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am reading `DataMatrix` barcode from a large image that consist some text also.For reading i am using `ZXing` library but it's not able to read barcode in image. while if i am providing barcode as separate image it is reading that barcode.

I have done some google and found `ZXing` is not able to read `DataMatrix` barcode from a large image. So I want to pre-process my image before providing it to `ZXing`. I was thinking to extract barcode part from that large image. Is it possible? if yes then how i can extract barcode part from an image? Or any other Idea to do this?

Comment: What's the size of the image and also the barcode? How many barcodes does the image include?

Comment: Could you share the image link?

Comment: Yes my image file located on https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-xLpJw4-HOlN3FiRUljakl6TlU/view?usp=sharing